# F# WPF MVVM can I do this without making the view model variables mutable?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, f#

I'm learning F#, I want to build the next module of my home project.  So far most of my F# code has been test code written with the command line.  I also did some custom drawing to a Winforms Panel.  So far, I haven't had to use one mutable variable.  but now I'm trying to write some actual code and as soon as I got to the ViewModel part it seemed that I had no choice but to make the variables that will interact with the UI mutable.  Is this true, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Yes it is true - but you don't need make already used objects mutable. Just create "decorator" wrapper class with mutable properties. Another approach which I found will follow "right tool for the job" approach is using C# projects for view and ViewModels and F# for your "business" logic. For immutable values you can create converters which will create new instance on every change

Comment: I did consider doing the view models in c# when I started to realize this.  I think that that may be the way to go.  I find that the syntax that comes along with mutable objects is not as natural in f#.  Thanks.

Comment: For making (existing) classes mutable for infrastructure only, have a look at `CLIMutableAttribute`. Make sure that your design does not get polluted though and mutability is limited as much as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For MVVM, F# carries one very significant advantage: it does not allow circular dependencies. This makes it very difficult to break the pattern: i.e. to allow the model to directly affect the viewmodel, or the viewmodel to access the view. As Bent says, F# is multi-paradigm: it supports properties with getters and setters, and these are not things to be eschewed in the language.

It's interesting that I'm citing a lack of capability as one of the advantages of F#, but I feel it is precisely this preclusion of circular dependencies that makes the language a good choice for an enterprise architecture.

I have a toy project at https://github.com/SpiegelSoft/Astrid. You can look through that to see how I've implemented MVVM using ReactiveUI.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is true. The inherent nature of MVVM precludes immutability.

If immutability really is that important to you, then have a look at the MVC framework created by Dmitry A. Morozov. This is the project page on GitHub:

http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Desktop.UI/

I am not sure I would use it, since so few others do, but it is definitely worth studying.

As for the language;

If I remember correctly, they initially experimented with Haskell, but then decided Ocaml was more practical. So that's what F# is based on. Haskell is as pure as they come, which became a problem in the .NET world, while F# is a multi-paradigm language better suited for the real world needs in .NET.

So don't feel bad about using mutable in F# in some cases. I will go so far as to say you are meant to. It's not bad at all, and in the long run it still gets the job done more efficiently than with C#.